# Why when I use .size() to compute the length of array in the Conditional Determination of for Loop Structures will time out in leetcode?

Tags: arrays, time-complexity, timeout, size

I noticed a particular timing behaviour while solving LeetCode problem [27. Remove Element](https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-element/description/):

> Given an integer array `nums` and an integer `val`, remove all occurrences of `val` in `nums` **in-place**. The order of the elements may be changed. Then return *the number of elements in* `nums` *which are not equal to* `val`.
>
> Consider the number of elements in `nums` which are not equal to `val` be `k`, to get accepted, you need to do the following things:
>
> - Change the array `nums` such that the first `k` elements of `nums` contain the elements which are not equal to `val`. The remaining elements of `nums` are not important as well as the size of `nums`.
> - Return `k`.

When I submitted the code below, I got a time-out:

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    int removeElement(vector<int>& nums, int val) {
        int count=0;
        for(int i=0;i<nums.size();i++){
            if(nums[i]==val){
                for(int j=i;j+1<nums.size();j++){
                    nums[j]=nums[j+1];
                    count+=1;
                }
                i--;
            }
        }
        return nums.size()-count;
    }
};
```

Then I tried to use a variable to record the value of `nums.size()` and use it as the loop condition. This time the code finished within the alotted time.

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    int removeElement(vector<int>& nums, int val) {
        int count=0,size=nums.size();
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
            if(nums[i]==val){
                for(int j=i;j+1<size;j++){
                    nums[j]=nums[j+1];
                    count+=1;
                }
            i--;
            size--;
            }
        }
        return size;
    }
};
```

I don't understand why this could be such an important difference.

**I would like to know the time that `.size()` uses and its internal code, with its time complexity.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `nums.size()` on each iteration or storing it in a variable first does not actually make much of a difference. The real issue is that you run into an infinite loop when the last element is the value to remove, as you keep attempting to shift the remaining elements (of which there are none) down over and over. In the second version of your code, you decrement the size when shifting, which precludes going into the section of the `vector` that contains useless elements not part of the solution.

On another note, since the question states that the size of `nums` after the method executes doesn't matter, you can directly delete the matching elements from the vector. This can be easily done in one line with [`std::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase2) (which has linear time complexity).

```cpp
int removeElement(vector<int>& nums, int val) {
    std::erase(nums, val);
    return nums.size();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer sincerely. It helped me to find the real logical issue of my codes.

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity of [vector::size](https://cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/size/) is constant ([source code](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/libstdc++/api/a01069_source.html)). But as Unmitigated explained, that is not the issue with the first version of your code.

With the working version you're actually lucky that the tests are only with vectors of sizes up to 100, as your algorithm is not efficient: it has a O(²) time complexity in the worst case. To illustrate, if the input `nums` has 100 elements, and they are all equal to the given `val`, then your algorithm will move 99 elements, then 98 elements, then 97, ..., so in total there will be 1+2+3+..+99 movements, which is 4950.

There is a hint in the code challenge: *"The order of the elements may be changed."*. This means that instead of shifting all values that come after an occurrence of `val`, you could take the *last* value from the (active part of the) vector and overwrite that occurrence with it. Then reduce the `size` and you're ready to continue. This eliminates the inner loop you have.

Here is a spoiler implementation of that idea:

> `class Solution {
>  public:
>      int removeElement(vector& nums, int val) {
>          int size = nums.size();
>          for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
>              if (nums[i] == val) {
>                  size--;
>                  nums[i] = nums[size];
>                  i--;
>              }
>          }
>          return size;
>      }
>  };`

Another approach is to start with `size` equal to zero, and have `i` iterate the whole vector, and when there is a "good" `nums[i]`, copy it to the `size` index, increase `size`. That way you make the values "jump" to their final destination, and at the end `size` will be what you want it to be.

Again an implemantation:

> `class Solution {
>  public:
>      int removeElement(vector& nums, int val) {
>          int size = 0;
>          for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++) {
>              if (nums[i] != val) {
>                  nums[size++] = nums[i];
>              }
>          }
>          return size;
>      }
>  };`

Comment: Thank you for helping me revise the problem description to make it more accurate and giving me a better algorithm that better fits the requirements of the topic!